# How can I make executables included in a Ruby gem runnable on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

I have a Ruby gem with some scripts that are distributed as executables. On Linux, this means that they go on the PATH with the executable bit set when the gem is installed. But on Windows, I don't see that or anything equivalent. So, how can I make those scripts usable from the command line on Windows?

I noticed that the `Gem::Installer` package has a [`generate_windows_script` command](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0_preview1/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Installer.html#method-i-generate_windows_script), which from the brief description appears to match what I'm trying to do. Can I use that to help here, and if so, how?

Comment: Doesn't RubyGems automatically generate wrapper scripts (shell scripts on Unix, DOS COMMAND.COM batch scripts on Windows) for all installed binaries? At least that's how it worked back when I was still using Windows. I never had to do anything to get my scripts to be callable from the Windows command line.

Comment: You're right. I realized later that the batch wrapper scripts had in fact been there the whole time. One thing that confused me was that I used a `.rb` suffix in the the executable name, so unlike executables from other gems, Windows would only run mine if I used the full name of the wrapper script, including the `.bat` extension.